# Is there a canonical definition of "emotion" that spells out what Data can and cannot feel?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Data, pre- "Generations", famously claims that he cannot feel emotion. However, the exact definition of "emotion" is not made clear in the series, as far as I know. Clearly he feels curious, and has often referred to things as "fascinating". Both of these could be called "emotion".

Is there anything written, either in stories/film or manuals for the writing staff, that clearly define what Data can and cannot do in terms of expressing emotion?

Comment: He feels whatever the script needs him to feel in that scene, despite us being repeatedly told that he has no feelings.

Comment: I'd guess if it involves pleasure or pain or has a connotation of positive or negative- Data can't do it.  Thus happy or sad - no.  Curiosity is just an imperative to get more information.  Familiarity an acknowledgement of information already understood and friendship  an acknowledgement of both familiarity and usefulness.

Comment: I don’t think we have a canonical definition of emotion [in real life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotion), so unless the _Star Trek_ writers really do have access to 24th century science, it’s probably about as well-defined as Klingon honour or [the Prime Directive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156656/440).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I kindly disagree about Klingon honour, which is somewhat well-defined in the series, but it seems most Klingons (TNG/DS9 eras) are hypocrites about it (see K'mpec et al) and were called out on this by Picard, Worf et al.

Comment: Overall I think the problem you are asking about is one that has been present since Spock, and is still present in Isaac.  Even a sentient computer would still not be self motivated, but that doesn't make for a good screen character.

Answer (score 3):

I think what explains your confusion is this. Data doesn't not feel emotion because it's somehow lacking in his design. Data doesn't feel emotion as a safety feature.

Data is an interesting character. For the casual viewer he is just an android with the trope no emotions, and that's good enough. But things get much deeper if you pay attention to the show. Data is the 2.0 model. He has an older brother  Lore.
Lore was allowed to develop without emotional locks, and he became a psychopath. So for the second model, Dr. Soong added blocks to prevent Data from feeling emotion. This way his positronic brain could mature, and then later he can be given the emotion chip to unlock his emotions.

This is confident with similar ideas to other science fiction like Blade Runner where the replicants are psychopaths because they are made to be adults, but are only only two years old.

So to answer your question, Data can't feel emotions that Dr. Soong considered to be emotions. Just a limit of one self admittingly flawed human being's opinions.

EDIT

Having given this more thought. In the episode where Data creates Lal he says that he can't use contractions. Microsoft Word can figure out contractions. Clearly there are things blocked from his ability to do.
Data is unaware of these blocks, so when he creates Lal, she doesn't have them. Because of that she can use contractions and experience emotions.

Comment: I am fairly confident that Data had more than "just a block". While Data may or may not have had the hardware for emotional emulation (this is unclear), at the very least he did not have the software for it. This is indicated pretty clearly in TNG *Brothers* and *Descent*.

Comment: What's "Baserunner"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Blade Runner. Fixed

Comment: "Data ... says that he can't use contractions."    Hmmm.

Comment: @Pete Here is a video on the topic. A bunch of clips where it comes up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY1KdQNodN0

Comment: I wonder if you missed the point. Data says he CAN'T use contractions, but CAN'T is a contraction.

Comment: @Pete well yeah, that video was made to point out some production errors, but we're talking about in universe right now